# how to show image file from directory in a fancy box

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am working on page where I want to show an image from anchor's href to a fancy box.

**Html :-**

```
<a href="D:/myImage.jpg" class="viewImg"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg fa-clr"></i></a>
```

Below is **jQuery** code I am using but its not working :-

```
$("a.viewImg").fancybox({
    type: "iframe",
    width: 380, // or whatever
    height: 280,
    tpl: {
        error: '<p class="fancybox-error myClass">Error in loading.</p>'
    }
});
```

I am getting an error at console "**Not allowed to load local resource**".

It should also display some message like "Error in loading." if file is not there in the directory, TIA.

Comment: `Not allowed to load local resource` pretty much tells it. You can not simply open a local computer ressource, as this could be a potential security issue. Have you tried using `file:///D:/myImage.jpg` ?

Comment: no its not working, in chrome popup shows "d’s server DNS address could not be found." and in firefox loader is continuously running without any popup ..

Comment: Move your code to webserver or install one locally.

Comment: okay @Janis but how to handle it in firefox here loader not stopping..